# Qt::FramelessWindowHint setSizeConstraint sideffects on closeevent

Tags: c++, qt

When using Qt::FramelessWindowHint with setSizeConstraint my widget does not recieve close events anymore, is this a bug? Minimal test example:

pro

```
QT       += core gui
TARGET = QT-BUG
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp
HEADERS  += widget.h
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget(){}
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QCloseEvent>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool
                   | Qt::FramelessWindowHint
                   | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    QVBoxLayout *l2 = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    l2->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
    this->setLayout(l2);

    QLineEdit* _inputLine = new QLineEdit(this);
    l2->addWidget(_inputLine);
}
```

main .cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window events like Close and Minimize are actually tied to the existence of buttons.  Bit of a poor design choice by the Qt folks.

It seems that `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` removes/disables the buttons, but you can re-enable them (without displaying them) via other window hints.  For close events, add `Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint`.